# Yeoman Source Control Angular generator, Mercurial what to ignore

Tags: angularjs, mercurial, bitbucket, yeoman

I have generated my project using Angular Generator using Yeoman.

I am just about to insert it into bitbucket using Mercurial and just wondering what folders I can ignore ?

I couldn't see any HG ignore files for this ?

I mainly wondering about two folders

- bower_components
- node_modules

Should they be in source control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, both should be ignored by Mercurial since they will contain auto-generated files (NPM modules and Bower components, respectively).